# Case statement to find 90 days between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two different table and I'm trying to create a case where if the 'A date' is between 90 days from the 'rollment date'.

First table

```
  Member ID       rollment date
       1           11/1/2014
       2           4/1/2015
       3           1/1/2014
       4           2/1/2014
       5           6/1/2014
```

Second Table

```
       Member ID    A        A date
           1       Yes     12/5/2014
           2       Yes     6/9/2015
           3       Yes     6/5/2014
           4       Null     Null
           5       Yes     7/25/2014
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
   Member ID    Enrollment      Within 90 days
    1             11/1/2014           Yes
    2             4/1/2015            Yes
    3             1/1/2014            No
    4             2/1/2014            No
    5             6/1/2014            Yes
```

My sql query looks like this:

```
       SELECT  
        a.MemberID
       ,a.rollment
       ,Case when B.A date between a.rollment < '90' then 
       'yes' else 'no' end      

   FROM [Database].[dbo].[Test] a   
   left join [database].[dbo].[Test2] b on a.MemberID = B.MemberID
```

Would someone help me.

Comment: what is the problem please explain more

Comment: My case statement is incomplete and didnt know how to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use datediff, like this:

```
SELECT  
    a.MemberID
   ,a.rollment
   ,Case when datediff(day, B.[A date], a.rollment) < 90 
         then 'yes' else 'no' end
FROM 
   [Database].[dbo].[Test] a   
   left join [database].[dbo].[Test2] b 
       on a.MemberID = B.MemberID
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond. but i got an error message of 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' how would i go by this?

Comment: @Amaury You're storing the dates in the database as string? If possible, you should try to change that. If there is no possibility to do that, you can use convert(date, fieldname, 101) to do that in the query and 101 is the format code for mm/dd/yyyy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx